# image-url and images_dir in pyScss?

Tags: python, compass-sass

I'm trying to use the [`image-url`](http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/urls/#image-url) Compass helper in scss files as described in [this blog post](http://blog.grayghostvisuals.com/compass/image-url/), but I'm unable to find a way to set `images_dir` (or an equivalent) in [pyScss](https://github.com/Kronuz/pyScss).

I've looked through the docs and [some of its code](https://github.com/Kronuz/pyScss/blob/master/scss/__init__.py#L3322), and pyScss doesn't seem to have any place to set this value, but it does [claim to support `image-url`](https://github.com/Kronuz/pyScss#support).

Is it possible to specify an images directory in current versions of pyScss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, pyScss has no support whatsoever for either `images_dir` or `images_path`.

Instead, `image-url()` paths are *always* looked up against the `STATIC_ROOT` config variable *only*.

Small comfort: `STATIC_ROOT` can be a callable that yields `(filename, storage)` tuples; for `image_url()` it'll only use the first value yielded. The `storage` object needs to implement the [Django `Storage` API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/files/storage/#the-storage-class) (it'll use the `.modified_time()` and perhaps the `.open()` methods), so you could perhaps use *that* to intercept `*.jpg`, `*.png`, etc. paths to 'redirect' to your images dir of choice.

The generated URL however will (stubbornly) consist of `STATIC_URL` + the path passed to `image_url()`.

I suggest you add a feature request / bug report to the [issue tracker](https://github.com/Kronuz/pyScss/issues) to request they add *proper* support for setting `images_dir` and `images_path` instead.